# SwiftUI two columns of text

Tags: swiftui

I have a dynamic array of Strings, that I want to display in a 2-column format. This is my first stab at it:

```
    ForEach(0..<theWords.count, id: \.self) { ind in
        HStack {
            if ind.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                Text(theWords[ind])
                    .offset(x: -65, y: 0)
            }
            if !ind.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                Text(theWords[ind])
                    .offset(x: 65, y: -24)
            }
        }
    }
```

But very inelegant! What is a better way to do this?

Comment: ForEach(0..<5) { x in is only for static data and never use Id:.\self or you’ll crash, you need to make data conform to identifiable or supply a unique identifier key of the data struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LazyVGrid` can be made to achieve your two-column layout:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let theWords = ["Cat","Dog","Rat","Hamster","Iguana","Newt"]
    
    let columns: [GridItem] =
             Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(theWords, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Important note:
*Using `.self` for the `id` in a `ForEach` is *not safe* unless it is guaranteed that each word is unique and won't change locations in the grid (such as in my example where `theWords` is an immutable array). If either of those is not the case, make sure to give each word a unique ID*

Comment: Hi, the text shows up centered in the column. What I'd like is the text left aligned within the column, how to do that? Thx.

Comment: You can use a frame modifier with an alignment. You may need a container stack on the Text to do that. If you need a more complete answer, it’s probably a good opportunity to start a new question.

Comment: I used: GridItem(.fixed(150), spacing: 16, alignment: .leading), that did it.